# Inner joining two tables returns empty result

Tags: sql

I am trying to get two tables that aren't related to pull a column of data each.

I have one table called `AlphaData` and one called `TLAuth`. Each includes a column that is labelled `invoice` and I need to pull both columns so I can at least start a comparison. `TLAuth` will include *some* of the invoice numbers from `AlphaData`, but not all of them.

Right now I am using the following code:

```
SELECT Alphadata.Invoice, TLAuth.Invoice
FROM Alphadata
INNER JOIN TlAuth
ON TLauth.TLAUthID = Alphadata.TLAUthID;
```

But every time I run this it comes up totally blank. There is definitely data in there, I can pull one column of data from each, but not both at the same time. I have even setup a relationship (1 to Many from TL Auth to Alphadata) and it doesn't seem to work so any help would be grand.

Comment: Can you share any sample data? It might be that your IDs don't mach.

Comment: An inner join will return only the records where the ID columns match. What are the ranges of the IDs in the two tables? Also, do you want to compare the Invoice columns or the ID columns?

Comment: Now that you've mentioned that, I've realised that my ID's in each of the tables (the foreign keys) are actually blank. I take that's the problem here?

Comment: Thanks folks. Sorted it now with a pointer from scaisEdge.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed on the topic of including personal introductions or sign-off lines in your question (In short - Just don't. It's never necessary.)

Comment: Just saw. Sorry Tomalak. Wasn't sure if there was a "Solved" button lurking that I hadn't found yet is all. Will intend not to do it again.

Comment: @Nik A question is considered "Solved" when there is an accepted answer. You can either select one of the exisiting answers or provide one of your own (if none of the existing answers is good enough) and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables could not match you should use left join

```
SELECT Alphadata.Invoice, TLAuth.Invoice
From Alphadata
LEFT JOIN TlAuth ON TLauth.TLAUthID=Alphadata.TLAUthID;
```

Comment: That kind of worked. It's given the Alphadata.Invoice column data now! The TLAuth is still blank though.

Comment: Done it! Changed it to compare the invoice ID's directly.

Thanks for the pointer Edge :)

Comment: Cheers dude... didn't know that!